# Outputting status as a number, code to change colour

Tags: javascript, php, status

I have added a 'status' column into my table and inputed numbers for them to be shown along with the id and content.

```
    $res_array = array();
    // fetch all the entires one by one
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        // put query result in php array
        $array = array('id' => $row['id'],
                       'content' => $row['content'],
                       'status'=> $row['status']); 

        // add into the big array


        $res_array[] = $array;  
    // update the list view
for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++){
    $("<li/>", {"id": res[i].id, "text": res[i].content + res[i].status}).appendTo(todo.list);
    // Extend the width if msg is too long
    if(res[i].content.length >= 35){
        $('#'+res[i].id).css("height","50px");
    }
}
```

Above you can see how it is being displayed, i still cannot get teh if statement to change the colour of the content.

I want the content to change colour depending on the status number.
I dont know the code but i would imageine it would be an if statement for the status, but i need help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So where are you exactly printing your data?

Comment: you could use a switch on `$res_array[key]['status']` to set a variable with the required hex color and then just set the background color

Comment: As of now it is printing beside the content which is a todo item, as this is a todo list, so it come up "need to book hotel 3" which is the content and the status. I would like the div which that patricular todo item is in to change to red or green depending on done or not, so the status can determine this

Comment: I would use an if statement if you had two codes. Otherwise a switch is the way to go. Then you could associated a css class to the error code.

Comment: right a css class would work too didn't think of that but from your code snippet I can't really see what you whant to do with `$res_array`

Comment: My todo list is in javascript, i thik the code should be something like if status==1... change background color?

Comment: or if status==1 set css class to whatever you want

Comment: I have added this in... if(res[i].status == 4){
  $('#status4').css()
}... However it comes up an error within my code saying "res not defined"

Answer (score 2):

If you have a finite and defined list of status codes then I would suggest simply adding them to a CSS class such as status5 and then define the colors/style for each of the status codes you return as a basic CSS rule

```
.status5 { color: red }
```

Comment: then you can use on the output class="status<?php echo $row['status'];?>" which would give you the status #.